# PHP and node.js on the same server

Tags: php, node.js, port

I am using PHP for the backend of my website and I am introducing a node.js chat. I have everything figured out as far as authentication between the two, and my only problem now is switching between port numbers. How is this handled? Ideally I'd like to hide the port number and I've tried virtual hosts for this, but no matter how I configure the virutal host the server does not load and appears to be down. I am using cloudflare if this matter. But hiding the port isn't required. I just want to smoothly link to the chat app on port 2053 from the PHP app on port 443, and have the chat app link back to the PHP site. PHP uses apache. I can't find any easy way to do this. Been at this problem for days.

Comment: What are you using for your front end server?

Comment: Apache and php on port 443. I just want to create a link to port 2053 which loads a php page. Links on that page are set to go to 2053, but I want them to lead back to 443.

Answer (score 1):

After much much research, trial and error I've figured out a few things.

My site consists of mainly PHP, I want to use node.js on a separate page as a chat app. I thought this would be easy, but I was mistaken. It's a lot of pain to get both node.js and PHP to work together flawlessly, and if I knew back then what I know now I might have went a different route. But I have things working for the most part and I am happy.

Some useful info:

If you want to link back to 80 or 443 from your node page, use the full URL with http/s.

If you want to use a virtual host it's only possible on Apache 2.4+ because socket.io can't communicate through it without some apaache mods that allow websocket proxing. It's also possible with NGINX from what I hear but I am less familiar with it.

So in the end I am just keeping the port number and allowing hyper links between the two. This is a temporary solution until I upgrade to either Apache 2.4 or NGINX.